# Icons or Icons in legend area using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple form with a legend using Twitter Bootstrap. I want to be able to put things, at this point in time icons, beside my legend verbiage that are aligned right.

I have tried a few tags like div and it pushes the icon to the bottom of the legend line. I would like this to align with the legend text.

A short example.

```
    <legend>Contact Categories<div align="right"><i class="icon-comment"></i></div></legend>
```

This will cause the icon to drop all the way against the legend line. The legend itself stays as it should.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share some form of screenshot? Hard to know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would use `align="right"`. The problem is that your `<div>` is a block, it can't stay on the same line as the text.

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/Qysuj/)

You have to either make it float (right or left) :

```html
<legend>Contact Categories<div class="pull-right"><i class="icon-comment"></i></div></legend>
```

Or make it inline

```html
<legend>Contact Categories<div id="myBlock" class="inline-block"><i class="icon-comment"></i></div></legend>
```

```css
.inline-block { display: inline-block; }
#myBlock { text-align: right; width: 30%; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. This worked perfectly. I can't vote up yet but I did mark it as an answer.